# Subscribing to Twitter updates from Google Reader

Tags: twitter, google-reader

I asked a similar question [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/how-to-read-twitter-updates-from-google-reader) and found a workaround for what I wanted.  The workaround was subscribing to the RSS feed for each individual Twitter page.  This has worked acceptably for a while, but now with the new Twitter there do not appear to be any RSS feeds for me to follow.  Ideally what I would want is a feed or collection of feeds that updates for everyone that I am following.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up a [list](http://blog.twitter.com/2009/10/theres-list-for-that.html) and create a custom RSS with this app: [TwitterList2RSS](http://twiterlist2rss.appspot.com/)

Comment: That's an awesome idea.